# Allowing a user to run multiple copies of the same program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

My customer has my VS2008 Windows Forms application installed. He wants to be able to run multiple copies of it on the same PC. The first time he selects the program icon, it starts and runs fine. When he tries to start a second version of the same program, nothing happens.

There's no problem with computer resources. The program collects data from a custom USB device. When he wants to collect data from a second device, he wants to start another copy of the application running. There could be > 2 devices attached needing application programs running. In the days of VB6, this wasn't a problem.

Any suggestions short of installing multiple copies of the application?

Comment: I've never had this problem, have you actually tried to open two instances of the program yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed this on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually controlled through the project settings.

To fix this, open the properties of the project, select the Application node and ensure that `Make single instance application` is unchecked.

Comment: I don't see this with C#, but I have seen it with VB. Does it exist in C#?

Comment: Sorry, I must have had VB on the brain. You are correct, this of course does not apply to C#. Is there a shared resource that you are attempting to access (such as a file) that the first application is grabbing? Are there any exceptions (such as app crash) logged when the second instance starts?

Comment: No, no visible exceptions, no shared resources, no new processes or applications loaded in Task Manager.

Comment: I apologize -- I found a shared resource that wasn't being properly shared. Everything's fine now.